# Performance over PostgreSQL conditional join - Query optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Let's assume I have three tables, `subscriptions` that has a field called `type`, which can only have 2 values;

1. FREE
2. PREMIUM.

The other two tables are called `premium_users` and `free_users`. I'd like to perfom a LEFT JOIN, starting from the `subscriptions` table but the thing is that depending on the value of the field `type` I will ONLY find the matching row in one or the other table, i.e. if `type` equals 'FREE', then the matching row will ONLY be in `free_users` table and vice versa.
I'm thinking of some ways to do this, such as LEFT JOINING both tables and then using a COALESCE function the get the non null value, or with a UNION, with two different queries using a INNER JOIN on both queries, but I'm not quite sure which would be the best way in terms of performance. Also, as you would guess, the `free_users` table is almost five times larger than the `premium_users` table. Another thing you should know, is that I'm joining by `user_id` field, which is PK in both `free_users` and `premium_users`

So, my question is: which would be the most performant way to do a JOIN that depending on the value of `type` column will match to one table or another. Would this solution be any different if instead of two tables there were three, or even more?

**Disclaimer:** This DB is a PostgreSQL and is already up and running in production and as much as I'd like to have a single `users` table it won't happen in the short term.

Comment: You can use partitioning by inheritance to create the appearance of a unified users table with no downtime or reorg needed.

Answer (score 0):

What is the best in terms of performance?  Well, you should try on your data and your systems.

My recommendation is two left joins:

```
select s.*,
       coalesce(fu.name, pu.name) as name
from subscriptions s left join
     free_users fu
     on fu.free_id = s.subscription_id and
        s.type = 'free' left join
     premium_users pu
     on pu.premium_id = s.suscription_id and
        s.type = 'premium';
```

You want indexes on `free_users(free_id)` and `premium_users(premium_id)`.  These are probably "free" because these ids should be the primary keys in the table.

If you use `union all`, then the optimizer may not use indexes for the joins.  And not using indexes could have a dastardly impact on performance.